# Does IE support 'copy' event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, cross-platform, dom-events

I need to catch users keyboard 'copy' event, and do some customized thing when it's fired. (should support IE too)

I currently implemented it in this way :

```
document.addEventListener('copy', onCopy);
```

With this I don't need to distinguish ctrl+c or cmd+c for different OS
However I found different answers for if 'copy' is supported in IE:

MDN:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Another site: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/

Is it supported by IE. If not, is there anyway that I can make a cross-OS 'copy' catching?

Comment: like MDN tells, this is simply not supported in IE. You have to search some `polyfills` for that

Comment: Looks like MDN document has some incorrect information. OnCopy event is working in Internet Explorer. I made a test with the sample code and find that event is working fine. Ref: http://help.dottoro.com/ljwexqxl.php

Comment: MDN documentation is for the "Clipboard API and events W3C draft" - perhaps IE's events have no connection to that particular API, rather some old buggy non-standard microsoft specific event

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncopy.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body oncopy="myFunction()">



<p id="demo">copy me</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You copied text!"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```